# Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning (Cordova Angular)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angular, cordova

When I execute in the cmd `cordova run android`, it returns:

```
Android Studio project detected
(node:6824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled Promise Rejection (rejection id: 1): Operation Failed
(node: 6824) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled Promise Rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections 
that are not handled will terminate the node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I don't understand the problem, if you have any advice for me. I've already read some other answers to this problem on stackoverflow but..
This is my code just below for

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {
// make sure android platform is part of build 
if (ctx.opts.platforms.indexOf('android') < 0) {
    return;
}
var fs = ctx.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
    path = ctx.requireCordovaModule('path'),
    deferral = ctx.requireCordovaModule('q').defer();

var platformRoot = path.join(ctx.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android');
var apkFileLocation = path.join(platformRoot, 'build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk');

fs.stat(apkFileLocation, function(err,stats) {
    if (err) {
         deferral.reject('Operation failed');
    } else {
        console.log('Size of ' + apkFileLocation + ' is ' + stats.size +' bytes');
        deferral.resolve();
    }
});

return deferral.promise;};
```

Thanx for your help.

Comment: Instead of rejecting `defarral` with just 'Operation failed' try to pass in the `err` object as well to get the error message.
Try `deferral.reject('Operation failed: ' + err);`
or `deferral.reject('Operation failed: ' + JSON.stringify(err));`

Answer (score 0):

The error means you need to handle exceptions that are thrown from promises.

```
promise.then(...).catch(...)
```

If you can't do that, you need avoid `deferral.reject`.